# Comparison time for 2 large MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have imported 2 .csv file that I wanted to compare into MySQL table. now i want to compare both of them using join.

However, whenever I include both table in my queries, i get no response from phpMyAdmin ( sometimes it shows 'max execution time exceeded).

The record size in both db tables is 73k max. I dont think thats huge on data. Even a simple query like

```
SELECT *
FROM abc456, xyz456
```

seems to hang. I did an explain and I got this below. I dont know what to take from this.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref    rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE  abc456  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    73017   
1   SIMPLE  xyz456  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    73403   Using join buffer
```

can someone please help?

UPDATE: added the structure of the table with  composite keys. There are around 100000+ records that would be inserted in this table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `abc456` (
`Col1` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col2` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col3` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col4` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col5` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col6` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col7` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col8` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col9` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col10` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col11` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col12` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col13` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`Col14` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `Col1` (`Col1`,`Col2`,`Col3`,`Col4`,`Col5`,`Col6`,`Col7`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Are you working on local MySQL server or it's some web host?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are doing a pure [catesian](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) join in your query.

Shouldn't you be joining the tables on certain fields? If you do that and the query still takes a long time to execute, you should put appropriate indexes to speed up the query.

The reason that it is taking so long is that it is trying to join every single row of the first table to every single row of the second table.

Comment: actually i did join on certain fields and even put indexes on 7 of total 14 columns...yet no improvements :(

Comment: @SunnyD'Souza Could you include your full query and indexes in your question so I can have a look into it? Also give an example of how many records there are in each table.

Comment: sorry mate for the extreme late and rather tardy response...but have update my question with the query for the structure of the table

Answer (score 1):

You need a join condition, some way of identifying which rows should be matched up:

`SELECT * FROM abc456, xyz456 WHERE abc456.id = xyz456.id`

Comment: ... otherwise you will get cartesian join, which means "all combinations: every row from table 1 with every row from table 2". If both tables have 73k rows you will get 5329000000 rows in result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add indexes on joining columns. That should help with performance.
2. Use MySQL Workbench or MySQL Client (console) for long queries. phpmyadmin is not designed to display queries that return 100k rows :)
3. If you REALLY have to use phpmyadmin and you need to run long queries  you can use Firefox extension that prevents phpmyadmin timeout: [phpMyAdmin Timeout Preventer (direct link!)](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/addons/11571/phpmyadmin_timeout_preventer-0.4-fx.xpi)

There is a direct link, because i couldnt find english description.

Comment: thanks for your reply mate, what I am trying to do is import the contents of a csv file into 2 db's and then compare them both. Now some files contain 50k+ records with 30 columns or more. I have found you cant create indexes on more than 16 columns. I need to perform join on all 30 columns to find difference between both as there is no primary key as such :( Suggest a easier solution if you have any.